# Adding child composable function with constraint layout into parent constraint layout in jetpack compose

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

i have planed to use constraint layout for my app. i want to include child composable with constraint layout into parent composable. when i try to do like normal way of including, it doesn't work, i tried like below. i am quite new to jetpack compose, can any one help me how to achieve this.

Main Activity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ConstraintLayoutTestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainNavScreen(Modifier)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainNavScreen(modifier: Modifier) {

    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Cyan)
    ) {
        val (
            child,
            doubleUpArrow,
            titleOne,
            titleTwo,
            arrowDown,
        ) = createRefs()

        LazyColumn(){
            items(50){
                Card(
                    modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(5.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Card List Items goes here",modifier.padding(10.dp))
                }
            }
        }

        BottomLayout()

    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomLayout() {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(child) {
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom, margin = 10.dp)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }
            .background(Color.Red)
            .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_keyboard_double_arrow_up_24),
            contentDescription =null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(doubleUpArrow) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                }

        )
        Text(
            text = "title one goes",
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(titleOne){
                    start.linkTo(doubleUpArrow.end, margin = 5.dp)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    end.linkTo(arrowDown.start, margin = 10.dp)
                }
        )
        Text(
            text = "title two goes",
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(titleTwo){
                    start.linkTo(doubleUpArrow.end, margin = 5.dp)
                    top.linkTo(titleOne.bottom)
                }
        )
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24),
            contentDescription =null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(arrowDown) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                }

        )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating some constrains using `createRefs` in your `MainNavScreen` Composable and then you try to access the reference variables in your `BottomLayout` Composable.

This will not work, as the variables declared in a parent Composable not are automatically available in the child Composable. Composables basically are Kotlin functions, so when you want a nested function to access values from the calling function, the calling function has to pass these values to the nested function as parameters.

However I think that you probably don't even need two `ConstraintLayout`s. Please try to modify your code as follows and report back if it fufills your requirements:

```
@Composable
fun MainNavScreen(modifier: Modifier) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Cyan)
    ) {

        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            items(50){
                Card(
                    modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(5.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Card List Items goes here",modifier.padding(10.dp))
                }
            }
        }

        BottomLayout()
    }
}
```

By using the [`weight`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#weight-in-row-and-column) Modifier, the `LazyColumn` will fill up all the remaining space above the `BottomBar`. I also changed `fillMaxSize` to `fillMaxWidth` to make each Card fill the full screen width.

Then update your `BottomBar` as follows:

```
@Composable
fun BottomLayout() {

    val (
        child,
        doubleUpArrow,
        titleOne,
        titleTwo,
        arrowDown,
    ) = createRefs()

    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)
    ) {
        // Images, Texts...
    }
}
```